# .NET Core 3.0 StringEnumConverter not serializing as string

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

When decorating your enum with:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public EventEntity Entity { get; set; }
```

And serializing it with
`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myEvent)`

You may notice that the enum is not serialized as a string but as the default integer.

Answer (score 26):

If you are using plain `System.Text.Json` without `Newtonsoft.JSON`, this snippet in `Startup.cs` might help:

```cs
// using System.Text.Json.Serialization
services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        });
```

The key takeaway here is the this converter defined in `System.Text.Json` (notice the class name is different from the one from `Newtonsoft.JSON`): [JsonStringEnumConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 25):

Simple one really but had me scratching my head for 20 mins or so...

When using the JsonConverter atribute, the first intellisense import is:
`using System.Text.Json.Serialization`

But you should instead use:
`using Newtonsoft.Json;`

Comment: Note, someone trying to answer this would never have guessed this, which is why it's very important to provide a Minimal, **Reproducible** code sample in your question.

Comment: This was the issue I had as well. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I also faced this issue. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 17):

Make sure to add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` NuGet package, and call AddNewtonsoft() right after AddMvc(...). If you do not, everything compiles fine, and seems to run, but in fact nothing works properly.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    
builder.Services.AddMvc()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

More details at [Newtonsoft.Json support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#newtonsoftjson-jsonnet-support)

Comment: All the above answers are right and for ASP.NET Core 3.0 and above this is the Silver Bullet! Thanks @delepster.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the Newtonsoft.Json libraries, find the latest version in the NuGet package manager, and add it to the project

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `System.Text.Json`, you can use `JsonStringEnumConverter` to replace `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter`.

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
   options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});
```